# Do I need a reducer for each property?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am following [this tutorial](https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start) that increments a number.

It works, but now I want to implement it for 100 or so config values.  Do I need to replicate counterSlice.js 100x or do I need to replace the number with an object with 100 properties?

counterSlice.js

```
export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: {
    value: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      // Redux Toolkit allows us to write "mutating" logic in reducers. It
      // doesn't actually mutate the state because it uses the Immer library,
      // which detects changes to a "draft state" and produces a brand new
      // immutable state based off those changes.
      // Also, no return statement is required from these functions.
      state.value += 1
    },
    decrement: (state) => {
      state.value -= 1
    },
    incrementByAmount: (state, action) => {
      state.value += action.payload
    },
  },
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions

export default counterSlice.reducer
```

Comment: You can do it through one reducer with an object with the 100 config values.

Comment: You can use an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases, it may be sensible to explicitly create functions for each state field. But if you literally have something in the order of 100 state fields, then you'll need a more generic approach.

I suggest including a `key` and `value` field in the payload of your reducer function.

```
export const configSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'config',
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    setConfigValue: (state, action) => {
      const { key, value } = action.payload;

      state[key] = value;
    },
  },
})
```

---